# Can anyone look into my AndroidSQLite query cursor?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

```
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fruits",null);
```

works but once I start adding restrictions like:

```
      cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT fruitName, color, 
       number FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%' AND fruitName LIKE 
      '%ppl%' AND number >=" + 5, null); 


       String[] fString = {"fruitName","color","number"};
        int[] tString = {R.id.fruit,R.id.color,R.id.number};
```

Then I keep getting an error here:

```
           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,R.layout.newLayOutForSQL,cursor,
            fString,tString,0);
```

I tried SELECT * FROM fruits in the db.rawQuery and it works perfectly but the restriction doesn't work

```
           SQLiteDatabase db;
```

db is set up properly so no worries

```
      cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT fruitName, color, 
       number FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%' AND fruitName LIKE 
      '%ppl%' AND number >=" + 5, null); 


       String[] fString = {"fruitName","color","number"};
        int[] tString = {R.id.fruit,R.id.color,R.id.number};


           ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,R.layout.newLayOutForSQL,cursor,
            fString,tString,0);
```

Expected: showing results with the restictions
actual results: error

Comment: What "*error*" are you getting? Please include the exact error message or stack trace.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting errors is because not specifying *, you are excluding the **_id** column, which is required for CursorAdapters.

As per :-

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not
>   work. Additionally, using MergeCursor with this class will not work if
>   the merged Cursors have overlapping values in their "_id" columns.
>   [CursorAdapter] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter) (*SimpleCursorAdapter is an indirect subclass of CursorAdapter*)

Try :-

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, fruitName, color,
   number FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%' AND fruitName LIKE 
  '%ppl%' AND number >=" + 5, null);
```

Or :-

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * 
   FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%' AND fruitName LIKE 
  '%ppl%' AND number >=" + 5, null);
```

Comment: do you happen to know why it's not showing anything in ListView when I add :   
         ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newList);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Probably because of the selection criteria being too exclusive. Try without WHERE clause it the same codes shows items then the selection criteria is too exclusive. So progressively add to the WHERE clause.

Comment: yeah it works without the WHERE clause and displays every piece of data in the database, but the cursor should display something with the WHERE clause because there is data that matches the restriction. How would you progressively add to the WHERE clause?

Comment: Step 1 `cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%'",null);`. step 2 `cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE color LIKE '%re%'  AND fruitName LIKE 
  '%ppl%'",null);` and so on .... Running each and seeing if you get any data.